# String + StringOps = functor?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

My simple understanding of a *functor* is that it is just something that can be mapped over `u.map(f)` with the following constraints:-

- `f` must be a function
- `f` can return any value and the type is allowed to change
- `map` must return a value of the same `Functor` ie. the shape and structure of the container must not change.

And an example.

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).map(x => s"$x")
res8: List[String] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

**My question:-**

`StringOps` will implicitly wrap a `java.lang.String` to extend it with operations common to indexed sequences - such as `map`.

But the following confuses me a bit.

```
scala> "Tera".map(x => s"$x").map(x => s"$x")
res12: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(T, e, r, a)
```

I assumed that `map` would return me just a `scala.Predef.String` rather than an `IndexedSeq[String]` since the definition of a *functor* is that it's shape/structure should remain the same.

Does this still meet the definition of a *functor* because `scala.Predef.String` IS-A `IndexedSeq[String]` ?

Comment: Afaik a string is a sequence of chars. So if you map that to a sequence of strings, you don't have a string any more.

Comment: A nice related snippet - https://medium.com/@joneshf/you-string-example-from-this-post-is-also-not-a-functor-https-medium-com-dtinth-what-is-a-6d1837a063b2#.b8uvdajs5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assumed that map would return me just a `scala.Predef.String` rather
>   than an `IndexedSeq[String]` since the definition of a functor is that
>   it's shape/structure should remain the same.

Not every type that has a `map` method adheres to the rules of Monad. A `String` in Scala does not hold the properties required from a monad. It isn't an [*endofunctor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Examples), and it doesn't hold natural transformations ([`join`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) (`flatten` in Scala) and [`return`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:return)(`apply`)).

As you can define `map` operations which are unrelated to monads, the following rules of the monad don't hold. You can `map` over a string to return the underlying integer values of each of it's characters:

```
scala> val s = "hello"
s: String = hello

scala> s.map(_.toInt)
res4: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(104, 101, 108, 108, 111)
```

Further, an `IndexedSeq[String]` is not a `String`. What you're doing is mapping over every character of the `String` and converting it into a `String`. That is why you get a sequence of strings in return. You can view a `String` as an `IndexedSeq[Char]`, definitely not as an `IndexedSeq[String]` though.

Comment: @Nio Question is - if invoking `map` on some functor instance changes the type of the very instance itself (e.g. changes `List` into an `IndexedSeq`), is it still a functor? I would say no, because functor's function `map(f: F[A])(f: A → B): F[B]` clearly states that result should be of type `F[B]`, not `Whatever[B]`. I don't see why @Yuval extended the discussion to monads, but anyways, relevant question for monad is - if invoking `flatMap` on some monad changes the very type of monad (e.g. `List.flatMap(whatever)` results in `IndexedSeq`), is it still a valid monad (answer is "no" again).

Comment: @slouc *I would say no, because functor's function map(f: F[A])(f: A → B): F[B] clearly states that result should be of type F[B].* I extended the question specifically to monads because the definition of `fmap` is defined on a monad, a specific case of a functor. Although a functor preserves identity and composition, it need not stay in it's category. That is what *endofunctors* do.

Comment: What do you mean by "definition on `fmap` is defined on a monad"? Functor defines map, while monad (specific case of a functor) defines flatMap. More specifically, on top of functor's `map`, it also defines `flatten` (join in haskell), which we then can (and in Scala we do) merge together into `flatMap` (bind in haskell). Right? I do like your point about not staying in its category though. I automatically assumed we are talking about endofunctors; if question refers to functors in general, then I agree with you. Term "functor" in programming often implicitly assumes endofunctors.

Comment: @slouc I think it all depends on what we're scoping this to, general category theory or specific implementations in Haskell/Scala. I was talking about the general categorial terms. If we talk about programming, then I disregard what I've said regarding the general functor and `fmap` :)

Comment: What's confusing for me is that sometimes I read that all functors in programming are in fact endofunctors because they map from a category back to that same category. Category in question is "category of types". So e.g. in Scala, you can `map` all you want but your result will always be a Scala type. So what's the correct viewpoint? If a functor maps a `List` and the resulting type is an `IndexedSeq`, is it still an endofunctor because it mapped back to category of Scala types, or is it *not* an endofunctor because it mapped a type to another type?

Comment: @slouc I'm not expert, but I think it depends on the definition of the category. If we're talking about "Category of all types", any functor which is not an endofunctor would take us to a completely new Category, be it as it may. Definitely an interesting question to ponder about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126530/discussion-between-slouc-and-yuval-itzchakov).

Answer (score 2):

No, `String` isn't a functor, precisely because it can only contain `Char`s.

> Does this still meet the definition of a functor because scala.Predef.String IS-A IndexedSeq[String] ?

It isn't (it isn't `IndexedSeq` of anything, it's only implicitly convertible to `IndexedSeq[Char]`), and it doesn't.